# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: com.google.android.apps.messaging.ui.conversationlist.ShareIntentActivity - Resources not found

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I created a game on Unity for Android. I got this error when uploading an update of my build on Google Play:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.android.apps.messaging.ui.conversationlist.ShareIntentActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08014a
```

I only changed the sound volume in the update, so I guess the issue was already there in the previous builds but not detected.

I used visual scripting. I  only have5 scripts downloaded from internet:

1. to allow to take a screenshot and share it on a platform when
   pressing a button
2. to adapt the game to the screen resolution of the device
3. to authenticate to Google Play and send the score to the leaderboard
4. to trigger an event when the Unity ad did finish
5. to keep playing the music when reloading the scene

Here is the detail of the issue:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.messaging, PID: 30735
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.android.apps.messaging.ui.conversationlist.ShareIntentActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08014a
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2805)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08014a
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValueForDensity(ResourcesImpl.java:229)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:876)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:819)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:605)
    at ym.a(PG:15)
    at com.google.android.apps.messaging.ui.common.ListEmptyView.a(PG:5)
    at nog.c(PG:20)
    at cy.b(PG:48)
    at nol.b(PG:15)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.g(PG:120)
    at em.f(PG:71)
    at ee.a(PG:447)
    at ee.c(PG:436)
    at ee.d(PG:395)
    at ee.a(PG:427)
    at ee.b(PG:327)
    at ee.a(PG:535)
    at ee.c(PG:217)
    at ee.c(PG:109)
    at ee.i(PG:61)
    at di.onStart(PG:114)
    at ma.onStart(PG:128)
    at vit.onStart(PG:60)
    at lkx.onStart(PG:33)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1334)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7033)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2768)
    ... 9 more
```

I am not a programmer so I don't know where to start. The error is about com.google.android.apps.messaging/com.google.android.apps.messaging.ui.conversationlist.ShareIntentActivity
So maybe it is related to script to share a screenshot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error just now, complaining about that exact resource ID `0x7f08014a`. It's not an error in *your* app. Looks like Google has some resource bug in their messaging app.

If you view the test-run video, I believe you will see something like Google's messaging app being started. Perhaps from a share button?

Comment: Yes , It happen after pressing the share button.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me , Thanks for sharing

Comment: Same issue here. All my app updates all always fail in my prelaunch report.

It's rather frustrating, as it runs the risk of hiding actual issues, and makes the prelaunch reports mostly worthless.

Anyone know how to report this to someone at Google empowered to fix this on their end?